# Why is fresh Monterey install ignoring clicks on the login screen?

Tags: mouse, login, monterey, login-screen

I have updated my Macbook Pro to macOS 10.16 Monterey. The OS boots and sends me to the login screen. However, I am unable to click the name and password fields. The clicks are completely ignored using both the trackpad and a Magic Mouse.

It should be noted that clicks are successfully registered everywhere else that is clickable on the login screen (e.g. the clock, restart button, etc.) Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was remedied by [resetting SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).